# How to add empty cells in UITableView without expanding it

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have UITableView with custom looking cells. Now user can scroll past the bottom and see that there are no more rows (cells) and see background. I want to create impression that there are more rows below, but they should not be added to tableview, so when user scrolls down, it bounces back to last useful cell.
TableFooter and subview expands content and user can scroll there (or maybe I was doing it wrong).

Right now I added new empty cells and after any action that may recount contentSize I specifically set contentSize to default setting. But I feel like it's not the right way (although it works). Is there some other way?

I tried searching, but it's hard to explain what I want in few sentences, not to mention in search line.

Comment: Just add some extra blank entries into your array (I assume you're using an array of strings), and save the last useful row.

Comment: @CodaFi oh, table cell initialization is much more complicated than by array of strings. I'm using C++ containers to fill cells almost arbitrarily. Nevertheless, I think empty entries would expand my table with blank cells and content size would expand appropriately, which is not what I need.

Comment: Content size?  How in the world would one "insert" without changing the one variable that has to change?  It's like asking for bigger pants with the same amount material.  I assume you mean you want just little blank separators, right?

Comment: @CodaFi i think we have misunderstanding. Imagine a bookshelf, that is filled with some books from above. A shelf is a cell. I want to show, that bookshelf doesn't end with last shelf that has a book on it, but continues below. But only show, no books there, no interaction. You move tableview and see: there are shelves below, but when you release your finger, table moves back to last shelf that contains something. Did that clarify something?

Comment: Yes.  Can you implement some kind of cell background pattern.  iBooks uses a couple of images that form a sort of UIColor pattern to give the illusion of infinite shelves.

Comment: @CodaFi I've watched this app and it seems to work exactly as mine. I don't know how to make this any way else than mine. If you can explain other ways in answer - I'd appreciate this very much.